# Dynamic inheritance in Tiles plugin Struts2

Tags: html, jsp, tiles

I'm using the Struts2 framework with the tiles 2.0.6 plugin. In my webapp, I have a "base" layout that consists of a header, a footer and the page content:

```
<definition name="sharedLayout" template="/shared/jsp/Base.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="pageHeader" value="/shared/jsp/Header.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="pageContent" value=""/>
    <put-attribute name="pageFooter" value="/shared/jsp/Footer.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

For some pages, this suffices. However, I also have several pages which all use the same subheader. The easiest way to deal with this would be to create an additional tiles definition:

```
<definition name="sharedLayoutExtended" template="/shared/jsp/BaseExtended.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="pageHeader" value="/shared/jsp/Header.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="pageSubHeader" value="/shared/jsp/SubHeader.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="pageContent" value=""/>
    <put-attribute name="pageFooter" value="/shared/jsp/Footer.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

However this has the major downside that I'm duplicating most of the code in Base.jsp (and base.css, base.js...) and BaseExtended.jsp. Making maintainance and development that much harder!

I tried to always use BaseExtended and then use the ignore attribute for those pages who don't have a subheader:

```
<tiles:insertAttribute name="pageSubHeader" ignore="true" />
```

And while this works, there are some element inside BaseExtended that should only be present if the attribute is acutally present. For example, if there is a subheader, then somewhere else in the jsp there should be a div with some stuff in it. I cannot add this special div inside my subheader.jsp because there are other element in between:

BaseExtended.jsp:

```
<body>

<tiles:insertAttribute name="pageSubHeader" ignore="true" />

...some other jsp stuff...

IF subheader is actually present, then have some stuff here
ELSE have nothing here

<tiles:insertAttribute name="pageContent" />

...some other jsp stuff...

IF subheader is actually present, then have some stuff here
ELSE have OTHER stuff here

</body>
```

Is there a way I can achieve these "if/elses"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [useAttribute](http://tiles.apache.org/2.2/framework/tiles-jsp/tlddoc/tiles/useAttribute.html) here if you want to test if pageSubHeader is exist.

Using JSTL

```
<tiles:useAttribute name="pageSubHeader" id="pageSubHeader"/>
<c:if test="${not empty pageSubHeader}">
    //do your stuff here. 
</c:if>
```

or scriptlets

```
    <tiles:useAttribute name="pageSubHeader" id="pageSubHeader"/>
    <%
    if(pageSubHeader != null) {
        //do your stuff or include your script
    } 
    %>
```

Or you can also use [importAttribute](http://www.konakart.com/forum/index.php?topic=1616.0) with [logic:not equal](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/logic/tld-summary.html). See related question [here](http://www.konakart.com/forum/index.php?topic=1616.0)

```
<tiles:importAttribute name="pageSubHeader" scope="request" />
<logic:notEqual name="pageSubHeader" value="">
  //do your stuff here
</logic:notEqual>
```

Not sure if it helps.

Comment: is this answer your question?